# AJAX quantity Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to do a quantity validation using Jquery. I want to check for following

1) that the number is a whole number

2) that it not letter

3) that they is not decimal

4) that the max number is 99.

**My current Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#button').click(function()
    {
        var pid = $('#pid').val();
        var length = $('#length').val();
        var Qty = $('#Qty').val(); // this is the quantity
        var Category = $('#Category').val();
        #Qty = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $Qty); // filter everything but numbers
        if ($Qty >= 100) { $Qty = 99; }
        if ($Qty < 1) { $Qty = 1; }
        if ($Qty == "") { $Qty = 1; }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'cart.php',
            type: 'POST',

            data: { pid:pid, length:length, Qty:Qty, Category:Category },
            success: function(data)
            {


            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: @saran banerjee can you help me with this please

Comment: @nnnnnn I MEAN IF someone types like `0.6`

Comment: @nnnnnn do i put this before ` $.ajax({
            url: 'cart.php',
            type: 'POST',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that any validation you do with JavaScript (with or without jQuery) should be repeated in your PHP code (obviously the syntax won't be the same), because you can't ever completely trust what is submitted by the browser (the user might have used dev tools to bypass your client-side validation).

Having said that, to answer your question on how to do the validation you've described with jQuery, given a variable `Qty` holding the user input you can test whether it is an integer between 1 and 99 using the following code:

```
if (!/^[1-9]\d?$/.test(Qty)){
    alert('Add meaningful error message here');
    return false;
}
```

The regex I've shown, `^[1-9]\d?$`, allows the first character in the string to be a digit between 1 and 9, and then an optional second character that is any digit (0-9). Which works out to all of the numbers between 1 and 99. (Actually that was just plain JS, not jQuery.)

In the context of your existing code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var pid = $('#pid').val();
        var length = $('#length').val();
        var Qty = $('#Qty').val(); // this is the quantity
        var Category = $('#Category').val();

        if (!/^[1-9]\d?$/.test(Qty)){
            alert('Add meaningful error message here');
            return false; // don't continue
        }    
        $.ajax({
            url: 'cart.php',
            type: 'POST',    
            data: {
                pid: pid,
                length: length,
                Qty: Qty,
                Category: Category
            },
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note that the PHP code that you showed in your question (that you later edited into the middle of your JS) doesn't make sense because it actually *changes* the value entered by the user to force it to meet the rules. E.g., user types "15.0" so your code removes the decimal to leave "150" and then decides that that is too big and makes it "99". So the user thinks they've sent you "15.0" and you've changed it to "99".

Note also that if you know that 99 is the largest permitted number then you can add `maxlength="2"` to the input element in question so that the user can't type more than two characters.

Comment: what do u think if i add another simple validation on the field to block `.`

Comment: if u r still here please what will be the best way to solved this  problem basically i have an hidden div which slides show and code the item added and the price and quantity. how will i stop the hidden div from showing if the quantity doesn't pass validation

Comment: The code I've shown _already_ blocks the "." (decimal point) character in the Qty field. The regex (as explained above) allows one or two digits. No other characters are allowed, so no dot or other punctuation and no letters.

Answer (score 1):

try this and let me know whether works or not :

first you need to check whether the input is number or not

```
if(isNaN(Qty))
{
   alert("Not a Number");
   return false;
}
```

next ever if its a float(which means decimal) you can simply change it to a integer by doing the following

```
Qty = parseInt(Qty); //so 1.5  becomes 1
```

next you simply make a checking whether Qty is between >= 1 and <= 99

```
if(Qty < 1 || Qty > 99)
{
    alert("The number must be between 1 and 99");
    return false;
}
```

I hope this satisfy all your conditions Amy.

Comment: thats great too but nnnnnn pretty much covered everything

Answer (score 0):

Doing it by math (allowing for notations like "0.1 E2" and so on)

```
// cast to a number
var n = Number(Qty.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, ''));
if (!isNaN(n)) {
    // force to nearest integer in bounds
    n = Math.max( 1, Math.min( 99, Math.round(n) ) );
}
else {
    //not a number
}
```

Comment: Hm, in which browser doesn't this work? (Casting to a Number, isNaN(), Math.max(), Math.min(), and Math.round() are basic JavaScript. Of course you would have to add some code in the else-clause for error-handling or setting a default value like "n = 1;".)